# Mysql, inner join and subquery

Tags: mysql, database

Hi I need help this question:

**Calculate and display every delegate’s no & name along with their attained credits versus the course’s code, name & credits.**

```
delegate    (StudentNumber,StudentName,Phone)
session     (Code,Date,Room)
take        (StudentNumber, CourseCode, Grade)
course      (CourseCode, CourseName,CourseCredits,)
module      (ModuleCode, ModuleName, Price,Credits,Course_Code(FK))
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT no,name FROM delegate

INNER JOIN module,take
ON module.code = take.code

INNER JOIN course
ON CourseCredits = Credits
```

That's all I have so far, any help would be appreciated, i know i have to use a sub query but not too sure where

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT no,name FROM delegate

INNER JOIN take ON take.StudentNumber = delegate.StudentNumber
INNER JOIN module ON module.code = take.code

INNER JOIN course ON CourseCredits = Credits
```

Does it help ?

Comment: Simply throwing the answer to their feet almost never helps.

Comment: Yeah i would like a little bit of an explanation please if possible

Comment: I ont know where to go from here though, im not asking for the answer just what i have to do :) thanks